# What would be the right way to do async post and get requests?

Tags: go

The official docs of go's HTTP package say that

> To make a request with custom headers, use Client.NewRequest and Client.Do

However, if a post request takes time to complete (async), does 'Client.NewRequest' and 'Client.Do' await for the response?

What would be the right way to do async post and get requests while having custom headers?

Comment: Go uses goroutines for concurrency. There is no need for an async api to make http requests.

Comment: so should I do some for-loop sending posts until the response is completed?

Comment: I think it depends on the response, if you want to know the response, you could use for-loop to do http-request and wait it, method 2: using goroutine and channel, the channel is used to receive the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use channel and goroutine

in pseudo code:

```
func sendRequest(resp chan *Client.Response, method, url string) {
   client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: redirectPolicyFunc,
}  
   req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
   response, err := client.Do(req)
   if err != nil {
}
   resp <- response
}

func getResponse(resp chan *Client.Response) {
    response := <- resp
}

canal := make(chan *Client.Response)
go sendRequest(canal, "GET", "http://google.com")
go getResponse(canal)
```